# Отключить строгий режим

Tags: mysql

не могу отключить строгий режим, т к не могу найти my.cnf, его просто нет. работаю на мак, ставил мускл dev.mysql.com, разбираюсь в доке типа надо инициализировать mysql_install_db, но там возникает ошибка за ошибкой, то прав не хватает, то еще что... подскажите куда смотреть?

Comment: Начните с публикации ваших действий и текста ошибки. А еще лучше - озвучьте изначальную цель

Comment: Устанавливайте требуемый режим при старте сессии, делов-то... `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';`

Comment: я разворачиваю проект, где в инструкции указано что необходимо отключить строгий режим mysql sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: Ну так установите нужный режим глобально... `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';`... вряд ли при разворачивании проекта сервер будет перестартовываться... или имеется в виду, что проект для работы требует этот режим?

Comment: Накрайняк почитайте тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos

Comment: спасибо, получилось)) SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';